# Heritability estimation for germination success

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, genetics

I am estimating heritabilities for some traits using a parent-offspring regression in R. For mid-parents this means that the regression coefficient of a linear model is equal to the heritablility.

However this approach seems to be wrong for the trait "Germination rate". This trait is given in percentages of germinated seeds and for most plants above 80%. Two examples, one with success rates and one with rates for the parent generation and binary results for the offspring:

```
set.seed(123)

# Offspring data as mean, the data is skewed and heritability high
parent = sqrt(runif(100,0.1,1))
offspring = parent * runif(100,0.8,1)
family = 1:100
mean = data.frame(family,offspring,parent)

# Offspring data as successes
binom = data.frame()
for (family in 1:100) {
  parent = sqrt(runif(1,0.1,1))
  for (y in 1:30) {
   offspring = rbinom(1,1,parent)
   binom = rbind(binom,data.frame(family,offspring,parent))
  }}

# Generalized linear models (Logistic regression)
mod.mean = glm(offspring ~ parent, data=mean, family=binomial(link=logit))
mod.binom = glm(offspring ~ parent, data=binom, family=binomial(link=logit))
```

**Questions**

1. In general it seems to be advisable to use logistic regression for such data sets (as seen in the code). This does not seem to allow a heritability calculation through the regression coefficient (as it is >4). How am I supposed to use this model to calculate h²?
2. Another way of doing this seems to be to estimate the heritability based on an underlying probability-scale (Gianola 1979). If this is the correct approach, how do I implement it for my data set?
3. Would it be possible to give the germination success for the parent generation as binaries? Leaving it as a mean seems like a bad compromise.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question. I would be grateful for any help you are willing to offer.

**Edit**

My usual approach was to create a linear model and calculate the heritability from the regression coefficient:

```
set.seed(123)
parent.height = rnorm(100,10,2)
offspring.height = (parent.height + rnorm(100,10,2))/2

Call:
lm(formula = offspring.height ~ parent.height)

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    5.15956    0.55265   9.336 3.34e-15 ***
parent.height  0.47376    0.05344   8.865 3.50e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

If we assume that this example uses the mean of both parents and the mean of the offspring (e.g. 3 per family), the heritability is estimated as 0.47376. But as percentages cannot be expected to be normally distributed if the mean is close to 0 or 1, this approach seems wrong.

Maybe I should also mention that I am working with self-pollinating plants, as that may complicate things further.

Comment: Can you clarify how heritability relates to a logistic model relating a binary treat? I am used to seeing it expressed as fractions of variance estimated in variance components models for continuously valued traits.

Comment: Also how can "germination success" be assessed as a heritable trait when parents who do not germinate can never produce offspring?

Comment: @AdamO I added an example for my usual approach. This approach does not give estimates for any variance components except for Va (by estimating the heritability).

Comment: We used seperate seeds for the germination experiment and the second generation. If too many plants were unable to produce viable seeds, it would indeed be impossible/impractical to use this trait.